# Sql Query Help in select statement/Oracle Discoverer

Tags: oracle

I have a table as follows.

```
Id        Code         Indicator
1         AB             
1         CD            Y
1         EF              
2         BC            Y
3         AB         
4         GH            
4         AB            Y
5         CD             
5         BC
```

Now I need to retrieve the ID's which do not have any indicator associated to them. In this case, the retrieved rows should be

```
ID    Code     Indicator
3     AB        
5     CD 
5     BC
```

Thanks to y'll I got it in sql but I have the same table as a view in Oracle discoverer. How do i write a report to get the same result?All help much appreciated!!

Comment: do you have 3 columns id,code and indicator ?

Comment: a little more clear way of asking would have avoided the flurry  of confusion and answers to this otherwise simple question :)

Comment: I can never figure out how to reply here... I am sorry if I have down voted someone...was just trying to reply. I already tried using the not null but the rows returned are not the ones I need. My indicator either has a Y or is null.

My problem is one id can have multiple codes and can have one or no indicators at all. I need to retrieve those rows which do not have any indicator on them at all, even if they have multiple codes. Does that make sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it (Warning: Untested):

```
select id, code
from table
where id not in (select id from table where indicator='Y')
```

Comment: the question is to get the ones with indicator not associated (which would mean NULL). it does not deal with the value 'Y' specifically.

Comment: @user551841 - All that shows is that a depressing number of people didn't read the question properly.

Comment: @Saket: In the table, the only non-null value of the indicator column is 'Y'. If you wish to use the subquery `select id from table where indicator is not null`, then knock yourself out.

Comment: Thanks @JackManey!!! Your query worked absolutely fine and as you explained the only non-null value of the indicator column is 'Y'

Comment: @Cindy:  I'm glad it worked.  :)  If you could accept the answer (by clicking on the check-mark-shaped-area next to my answer), I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE t1
WHERE T1.ID in (SELECT
                  t2.ID
                FROM Table t2
                GROUP BY t2.ID
                HAVING MAX(t2.Indicator) = 'Y')
```